# Scrapy handle missing path

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am building a forum-scraper for a university project. The page of the forum that I am using is the following: https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/163541-lego-ninjago-2019/&tab=comments#comment-2997338.
I am able to extract all the information that I need except for the location. This information is stored inside the following path.

```
<li class="ipsType_light"> <\li>
<span class="fc">Country_name<\span>
```

The problem is that sometimes this information and path does not exist. But my actual solution can not handle it.
Here the code I wrote to get the information about the location.

```
location_path = "//span[@class='fc']/text()"
def parse_thread(self, response):
        
        comments = response.xpath("//*[@class='cPost_contentWrap ipsPad']")

        username = response.xpath(self.user_path).extract()

        x = len(username)
            
        if x>0:
            score = response.xpath(self.score_path).extract()
            content = ["".join(comment.xpath(".//*[@data-role='commentContent']/p/text()").extract()) for comment in comments]
            date = response.xpath(self.date_path).extract()
            location = response.xpath(self.location_path).extract()

        for i in range(x):     
            yield{
                "title": title,
                "category": category,
                "user": username[i],
                "score": score[i],
                "content": content[i],
                "date": date[i],
                "location": location[i]
            }
```

One possible solution that I have tried was to check the length of the location but is not working.
Right now the code results in the following (sample data)

```
Title | category | test1 | 502 | 22 june 2020 | correct country
Title | category | test2 | 470 | 22 june 2020 | wrong country (it takes the next user country)
Title | category | test3 | 502 | 28 june 2020 | correct country
```

And what I would like to achieve is:

```
Title | category | test1 | 502 | 22 june 2020 | correct country
Title | category | test2 | 470 | 22 june 2020 | Not available
Title | category | test3 | 502 | 28 june 2020 | correct country
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem is that instead of selecting the specific information one by one. First I have to select the entire block where all the pieces of information and only then pick the single information that I need.